# Problems with SQL Mail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Ok, I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 on a small environment. I currently have the data on the same drive as the backups (I know, bad idea, but I just inherited this challenge). I have several jobs setup to notify me if they fail.

My boss is good with SQL and knows how to maintain the system, but is not a dedicated DBA, which is why they hired me. Well I was just going thru their setup for the AM jobs and they had several fail last night. Wondering why this did not generate any emails, I decided to do a little digging.

One thing I found was that the SQL Server Agent service was running under a domain login that really isn't used anymore except for SQL. I changed the agent to start under the "local system account" and restarted the service and the emails started coming in. The problem is, that the agent needs to run under the domain credentials due to some of the jobs that run.

How can I set the user account to have the privileges as the local system, to be able to run the emails? As soon as I set the agent back to the domain login, then the emails stopped working.

Comment: Can you grant local system access to the domain account?

Comment: The domain account is associated with the "administrators" group on the server already and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment until my reputation is higher so forgive me if this "answer" is off the mark. But the first thing I would check is whether the domain account has permissions to the MSDB database.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188719(v=sql.105).aspx

"To send Database mail, users must be a user in the msdb database and a member of the DatabaseMailUserRole database role in the msdb database."